# build own google connector using app script for connecting facebook insights and looker studio

Tags: facebook, looker-studio

I can't find related resources about this, may I ask:
how to build own google connector using app script for connecting facebook insights and looker studio, import data from facebook or instagram insights into looker studio?
THank you

I have tried to find but I can only find all the third-party connectors